# Isolated digital input to microcontroller using optocoupler

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, stm32, power-electronics

I am designing an I/O logic controller with multiple digital inputs. I am using an optocoupler(PC817) to provide isolation between sensor pulse output and microcontroller digital input(GPIO pin).
The sensor voltage is rated = 5vdc-24vdc
Microcontroller(STM32F401) supply Vcc=3.3v
Microcontroller GPIO input voltage=3.3v

[image]

I need help finding the appropriate value of resistors (both input and pull-up).

**If I'm missing any protection or noise-filtering circuit, please et me know.**

Comment: Your circuit indicates the the input is not isolated.

Comment: It's just an label. The input is connected from another source.

Comment: But you have the same GND net connected on both sides of the optocoupler - so it's not isolated.

Comment: yeah I forgot to put the ground reference of sensor power source

Comment: Why do you need the optocoupler in the first place?

Comment: @Lundin to provide isolation between sensor out and controller digital input

Comment: Well, doh... _Why do you need isolation_?

Comment: @Lundin because the sensor operating voltage is 5-24v and the controller operating voltage is 3.3v. Both are from different sources so.

Comment: "because the sensor operating voltage is 5-24v" So what? Just do a plain voltage divider. "Both are from different sources"  And you can't ground them together because...?

Comment: @Lundin  I've already mentioned before that I forgot to put the ground reference of the sensor power source

Comment: Again, you still haven't explained _why_ you must use separate grounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manufacturers/suppliers of electronic components describe their products in **datasheets**. You can read UTMEL's (SHARP's) [datasheet for PC817 optocoupler online](https://pdf.utmel.com/r/datasheets/sharpmicroelectronics-pc817xi-datasheets-6777.pdf).

Table **Electro-optical Characteristics** (page 4) specifies the photodiode current and forward voltage in the first row, where the column Parameter content is Forward Voltage. Photodiode voltage (values in columns MIN, TYP, MAX) is the voltage drop across the IR photodiode. This parameter is measured with the current through the photodiode as specified in column Conditions, \$I_F=20mA\$.

With these parameters, you can estimate the R2 value in the network SENSOR_OUT, R2, PC817 pin1 of your drawing. Take the typical forward voltage of 1.2V and the current of 20mA. This resistor is required if your sensor can sink current too great for your optocoupler and you should constrain the current to the values specified in the datasheet (\$I_F\$ MAX 50mA, typical 20mA).

If your sensor outputs a voltage signal of max 12V, you should select a resistor \$R_D\$ so that it provides a current of 20mA when the voltage across this resistor is 12V-1.2V=10.8V, so \$R_D\$=10.8V/20mA=540 Ohm. The calculated values are approximate values, you only have to guarantee that the currents/voltages are not violating **Absolute Maximum Ratings** (page 4) and at the same time the photodiode current is sufficient to safely turn the transistor on with IR light of the photodiode. If your signal is current and it is greater than 50mA, you can use a shunt to sink excessive current.

[image]

UTMEL's document PC817 Photocoupler [Application, Pinout and Datasheet](https://www.utmel.com/components/pc817-photocoupler-application-pinout-and-datasheet?id=296) gives an example of using PC817, section **How to use PC817**, where the author uses \$R_L\$ = 1K to pull high the collector pin of the transistor. More advanced use of the optocoupler requires the designer to adjust the time parameters and frequency response, varying the pullup resistor value \$R_L\$, see page 8 of the datasheet, Figs 13-16.

Here I'm giving you only introductory instructions on selection of resistor values. More advanced designs would require adapting the circuit to detection of spike-shaped vs. continuous signal levels, optimizing the timing or frequency parameters and maybe other adjustments with other circuit components besides resistors.

Comment: Yes, the calculation part is done. Now I'm seeking help for any protection circuit if required.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using the opto because the input voltage is higher, an opto is overkill. If you need an opto due to safety (unlikely with 24V) or noise, then just an opto is insufficient; You would need isolated or separate supplies and grounds too and isolation for *all other signals* crossing that power supply boundary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkXlbc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The main difference is the Zener clamps the voltage even when the 3.3V is unpowered which could be important if the pulse source can be powered while the 3.3V is unpowered. The Zener is slower and produces more heat in the diode, though heat is negligible due to the current limiting of the resistor.

The rail clamp diode can be faster if properly chosen (like a Schottky diode) with more flexible clamping voltage but needs 3.3V power.

Comment: Yes sir I understand your point. I've designed the ADC input using Zener clamp circuit. but in case of digital input I'm advised to use opto for isolation. So I need to calculate relevant parameters accordingly.

Comment: Then you need to isolate your power supplies and grounds too as well as all other signals, including that analog input or the opto is pointless. That is often more effort than it's worth.

Comment: A zener clamp is not a good idea for an ADC input!  The zener starts conducting well before 3.3V is reached and will give you measurement errors. Use a two diode clamp circuit. For your opto, a 10k resistor should be adequate on the output side. For the input side, use ohms law to calc the value for around 5mA of led current.

Comment: Are these digital inputs or analog? (Using analog just for convenience..?) Zener is fine for digital of course. Opto is already useless for analog, at any kind of accuracy beyond just on-off.

Comment: Your second circuit won't work with GND as shown. OUT is connected to GND.

Comment: @PStechPaul Right you are

Comment: @TimWilliams those are digital inputs and I forgot to add the sensor ground reference in the circuit.

Comment: @PStechPaul  I forgot to add the sensor ground reference in the circuit.

Comment: Also, D2 will only start conducting at 3.3V + Vfwd. Meaning some 4V.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, but you normally use a fast, low voltage drop diode like a Schottky for this kind of thing.